# \usebox with tikz-uml

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, tikz-uml

I would like to be able to reuse components in a state diagram using TikZ-UML. I created a `savebox` called `\giraffe` with two components inside and I would like to place these above the initial node and below the final node. The code doesn't seem to produce the required result. Any idea why?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]

\newsavebox{\giraffe}
\savebox{\giraffe}{
  \umlbasicstate[x=0, y=0, fill=pink, width=15ex]{test1}
  \umlbasicstate[x=3, y=0, fill=yellow, width=15ex]{test2}
}

\umlstateinitial[x=0, y=11, name=initial]
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=9, name=a, fill=white, width=15ex]{a}
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=6, name=b, fill=white, width=15ex]{b}
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=3, name=c, fill=white, width=15ex]{c}
\umlstatefinal[x=0, y=1, name=final]

\node [below of=final] {\usebox{\giraffe}};          % below final
\node [above of=initial] {\usebox{\giraffe}};        % above initial

\umltrans{initial}{a}
\umltrans{a}{b}
\umltrans{b}{c}
\umltrans{c}{final}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: the code above is compiling but `tikz-uml` is a non-standard package; it can be downloaded from [here](https://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/).

Comment: Using `\def` instead of a box approach wouldn't save computer cycles, but would save typing.  Which savings is your goal?

Comment: Saving typing. Will `\def` still allow me to choose the location of the inner nodes? [ Note: I was able to successfully do this using simple rectangles, but for some reason similar code does not work with `\umlbasicstate`. ]

Comment: Could you also post a code version that compiles, but contains all the extra typing that you would like to eliminate?

Comment: This one compiles on my machine. If it is not compiling it may be because the package `tikz-uml` does not come by default. I downloaded the `.sty` from https://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/.

Comment: Ok, I see it compiles.  I don't have the answer, but I suspect the problem has to do with the fact that you are trying to specify x and y coordinates in something that you are hoping will be able to float around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, this can be adapted to your need.  The key here is using a **separate** `tikzpicture` to store the box in which you are placing the components.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes}
\begin{document}

\newsavebox{\giraffe}
\savebox{\giraffe}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
  \umlbasicstate[x=0, y=0, fill=pink, width=15ex]{test1}
  \umlbasicstate[x=3, y=0, fill=yellow, width=15ex]{test2}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\umlstateinitial[x=0, y=11, name=initial]
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=9, name=a, fill=white, width=15ex]{a}
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=6, name=b, fill=white, width=15ex]{b}
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=3, name=c, fill=white, width=15ex]{c}
\umlstatefinal[x=0, y=1, name=final]

\node [below of=final] {\usebox{\giraffe}};          % below final
\node [above of=initial] {\usebox{\giraffe}};        % above initial

\umltrans{initial}{a}
\umltrans{a}{b}
\umltrans{b}{c}
\umltrans{c}{final}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With `TiKZ 3.0` you can declare and use `pics`. A `pic` is a short picture that you can reuse several times in your diagram. Next code shows how to use `giraffe` as a `pic`.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    giraffe/.pic={
        \umlbasicstate[x=-1.5, y=0, fill=pink, width=15ex]{test1}
        \umlbasicstate[x=1.5, y=0, fill=yellow, width=15ex]{test2}
    }%
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\umlstateinitial[x=0, y=11, name=initial]
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=9, name=a, fill=white, width=15ex]{a}
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=6, name=b, fill=white, width=15ex]{b}
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=3, name=c, fill=white, width=15ex]{c}
\umlstatefinal[x=0, y=1, name=final]

\draw pic[below of = final] {giraffe};          % below final
\draw pic[above of =  initial] {giraffe};        % above initial

\umltrans{initial}{a}
\umltrans{a}{b}
\umltrans{b}{c}
\umltrans{c}{final}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the result is different from Steven's solution but I don't know `tikz-uml` positioning system to do it. I've tried to replace `below of=` syntax (I think it's deprecated) with `below = of` but it also modified internal composition of `umlbasicstate` components.

Comment: Is it possible to provide both colors as argument? I checked `Section 18.3 Defining New Pic Types` of the manual and can do it for one color but not both. The idea would be to use it as `\draw pic[below of = final] {giraffe={colorA=pink, colorB=yellow}};` (syntax doesn't matter as long as both arguments can be provided). [ Note: I don't know if a new question is required for this. ]

Comment: I've added it as a new question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167556/47170.