# TikZ 3.0---Multiple arguments for `pic`

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic, tikz-uml

How do I provide multiple arguments for `pic`?

`giraffe` contains two arguments for colors, `#1` and `#2`. I would like to be able to provide these as `giraffe={pink, yellow}` or `giraffe={colorA=pink, colorB=yellow}`. The syntax does not really matter.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    giraffe/.pic={
        \umlbasicstate[x=-1.5, y=0, fill=#1, width=15ex]{test1}
        \umlbasicstate[x=1.5, y=0, fill=#2, width=15ex]{test2}
    }%
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\umlstateinitial[x=0, y=11, name=initial]
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=9, name=a, fill=white, width=15ex]{a}
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=6, name=b, fill=white, width=15ex]{b}
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=3, name=c, fill=white, width=15ex]{c}
\umlstatefinal[x=0, y=1, name=final]

\draw pic[below of = final] {giraffe={pink, yellow}};          % below final
\draw pic[above of =  initial] {giraffe={blue, green}};        % above initial

\umltrans{initial}{a}
\umltrans{a}{b}
\umltrans{b}{c}
\umltrans{c}{final}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the manual, `pic` is in *Section 18.3 Defining New Pic Types*.
This is in connection with another question where someone [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167549/47170) `pic`as an answer.

I've also checked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131293/arguments-for-tikz-style), but I'm having difficulty applying it to my problem with `pic`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When the command is a bit more complicated then you want to use the general syntax

```
\tikzset{pics/giraffe/.style={code={....with #1...}}}
```

The `/.style` is part of the `pgfkeys` handler mechanism and it has a direct analogue with two arguments namely `/.style 2 args`.  So you could write

```
\tikzset{pics/giraffe/.style 2 args={code={
  \umlbasicstate[x=-1.5,y=0,fill=#1,width=15ex]{test1}
  \umlbasicstate[x=-1.5,y=0,fill=#2,width=15ex]{test2}}}}
```

to be called as `\draw pic {giraffe={pink}{yellow}}`.  Similary there is `/.style n args={5}{code={...}}` that will define a version with 5 arguments.

However, there are other syntaxes available.  If it is just the colours you are setting then prehaps you would like to write

```
\draw pic {giraffe=pink/yellow};
```

This can be acheived with

```
\tikzset{
    pics/giraffe/.style args={#1/#2}{
      code = {
        \umlbasicstate[x=-1.5, y=0, fill=#1, width=15ex]{test1}
        \umlbasicstate[x=1.5, y=0, fill=#2, width=15ex]{test2}
    }}}
```

The first argument to `/.style args` provides a pattern which is used for extracting the arguments to be used in the code.

In your example this gives you:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    pics/giraffe/.style args={#1/#2}{
      code = {
        \umlbasicstate[x=-1.5, y=0, fill=#1, width=15ex]{test1}
        \umlbasicstate[x=1.5, y=0, fill=#2, width=15ex]{test2}
    }}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\umlstateinitial[x=0, y=11, name=initial]
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=9, name=a, fill=white, width=15ex]{a}
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=6, name=b, fill=white, width=15ex]{b}
\umlbasicstate[x=0, y=3, name=c, fill=white, width=15ex]{c}
\umlstatefinal[x=0, y=1, name=final]

\draw pic[below of = final] {giraffe=pink/yellow};          % below final
\draw pic[above of =  initial] {giraffe=blue/green};        % above initial

\umltrans{initial}{a}
\umltrans{a}{b}
\umltrans{b}{c}
\umltrans{c}{final}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```