# Creating a new shape

Tags: tikz-pgf

I read some documentation about how to create a new shape. But some things are still not clear to me. In fact I wanted to create a new shape representing a switch symbol: I did the code in `tikzpicture` environment. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, fit}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\switch[0] {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0, 0) -- (1, 0) (1, 1) -- (2, 0) -- (3, 0);
        \draw [->, thick] (2, 1) .. controls +(left:5mm) and +(up:5mm) .. (1, 0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\switch
\end{document}
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Instead of a new `shape` you can try with a `pic` (TiKZ 3.0), they are easier to understand and use. Some examples: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170686/1952, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/151772/1952