# Reuse tikz picture in another tikz picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have a TikZ picture

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm);
\draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);
\draw (0,1) arc (90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);
\draw[dashed] (0,1) arc (90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);
\draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which makes a small ball.

Is it possible to reuse this shape in another tikz picture?

I have another tikz picture in which I use

```
\draw[fill=yellow!30, fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1] (B) circle (0.7cm) node[right] {$A$};
```

Instead of `circle` I want my small custom ball. How is that possible?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of TikZ (3.0)?  If do, this has a new way of being done.

Comment: I think this can be a duplicate of [How can I draw a TikZ element multiple times against a shaded background?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126161/13304)

Answer (score 0):

> Unrecommended way

There are several ways, this one puts `tikzpicture` environment to another `tikzpicture` environment with help of a `\node`.

```
%! *latex mal-tikz-tikz.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\malpic{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \draw (-1,0) arc (180:360:1cm and 0.5cm);
  \draw[dashed] (-1,0) arc (180:0:1cm and 0.5cm);
  \draw (0,1) arc (90:270:0.5cm and 1cm);
  \draw[dashed] (0,1) arc (90:-90:0.5cm and 1cm);
  \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \shade[ball color=blue!10!white,opacity=0.20] (0,0) circle (1cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%End of \malpic...
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (B) at (0,0);
\node[fill=yellow!30, fill opacity=0.5,text opacity=1] at (B) {\malpic} node[right] {$A$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Embedding pictures inside pictures is generally not a great idea in TikZ.

Comment: I agree with Andrew: this should not be encouraged. There are several alternatives, all listed in [How can I draw a TikZ element multiple times against a shaded background?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126161/13304)

Comment: I was quite happy when I found this solution in older versions of TikZ. It is fair enough when dealing with TikZ v3 where `pic` and `external` library have been introduced. I'm marking my answer as unrecommended.

Comment: Have a look at this thread. I answered using a new `scope` with custom options for the embedding picture. The thread also covers the usage of the `pic`. [Link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170677/34759)