# Several arguments in tikzset pic

Tags: tikz-pgf, arguments

I want to pass more than one argument to a pic defined with \tikzset.

I tried this and it works:

```
\tikzset{
    Piece/.pic={
        \draw (0:1) -- (120:1) -- (240:1) -- cycle;
        \draw (0,0) node {$\Gamma_#1$};
    }
};

\pic {Piece={k}};
```

I get the following image:

[image: Triangle with one subscript]

But what I really need is to have two subscripts, as in this one:

[image: Triangle with two subscripts]

However, no matter what I write in the \pic command, it is treated as a string and associated to the #1 argument. I would like something like:

```
\tikzset{
    Piece/.pic={
        \draw (0:1) -- (120:1) -- (240:1) -- cycle;
        \draw (0,0) node {$\Gamma_{#1,#2}$};
    }
};

\pic {Piece={k,r}};
```

But this does not work.

How can I specify two different and independent arguments?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167585/43317

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can switch to the alternative definition of the `pic` style family such that `style 2 args` or `style n args`, `style args` stuff from the regular `pgfkeys` syntax can be used for arguments.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  pics/Piece/.style n args={3}{
    code = { %
          \draw (0:1) -- (120:1) -- (240:1) -- cycle;
          \draw (0,0) node[#2,#3] {$\Gamma_{#1}$};
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic {Piece={k}{draw=red}{fill=red!10}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, this is what he meant? :|

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. However, I tried this and for some reason it works for 2 parameters but not for 3.

Comment: @AitorPérezPérez See the update

Comment: Yes, that works. I changed the 2 to a 3, but I did not write "n args={3}", I don't know why "2 args" works but "3 args" does not.

Thank you very much!