# How to create a new symbol (with adjustable colors) in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, symbols, tikz-styles, characters

I have a naive question --- How to create a new symbol like the figure below (with adjustable colors) in the tikz?

[image]

I believe that it is doable with tikzpicture. For example, using tikzpicture, are we able to switch its black color to another color like the brown color?

Here is a working MWE template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate 

\fill[black]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

*I consider that you need a mathematical symbol.*
I built it as a `\newcommand` that invokes `\mathchoice` for a good scaling if it happens to be used as an index, for example.  It depends on an optional argument that gives the color.

**The code**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand*{\tmp}[2]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[color=#2, x={(#1 ex, 0)}, y={(0, #1 ex)}, xscale=1.2]
      \path[use as bounding box] (-.2, .05) rectangle ++(1.7, 2.1);
      \draw (.1, 2.2) -- ++(10: 1.)
      to[out=10, in=0] ++(0, -.9) --++(190: 1.1);
      \draw (.05, 1.75) -- ++(10: .55)
      to[out=10, in=80] ++(0, -.8) coordinate (M)
      to[out=260, in=90] (0, -.25);
      \draw (M) -- ++(10: .5)
      to[out=0, in=80] ++(-.05, -.5)
      to[out=260, in=110]
      (1.25, -.25); 
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\funnysymbol}[1][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{\colorlet{rgb}{.}}{\colorlet{rgb}{#1}}
  \mathchoice{\tmp{.8}{rgb}}{\tmp{.8}{rgb}}{\tmp{.6}{rgb}}{\tmp{.5}{rgb}}
}

\begin{document}

$X \funnysymbol Y$ \quad $X_{a\funnysymbol b}$ \qquad
$X \funnysymbol[red!60!black] Y$ \quad $X_{a\funnysymbol[blue] b}$

$X \mathbin{R} Y$ \quad $X_{a\mathbin{R}b}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks very much for this - I am learning from it +1

Comment: If one of the answers (that were given) is what you were looking for, you should accept it to change the status of the question.  If not, you should comment in a way or another to understand what is missing.

Answer (score 6):

Well, your MWE is not exactly an MWE (not even an MNWE), but is this what you are looking for? You can define `pic`s  with arguments (even [more than one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311435/several-arguments-in-tikzset-pic) if needed):

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{blurb/.pic={
     \draw[line cap=round, line width=4pt, #1] (0,0) to[out=10, in=10, looseness=4] (0,-1)
         plot [smooth, tension=1.2] coordinates{(0,-0.5) (0.3,-0.4) (1,-1) (0.5,-2) (0,-3)}
         plot [smooth, tension=1.2] coordinates{(1,-1) (1.4, -1.4) (1,-2) (2,-3)};}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic[scale=0.5] (a) at (0,0) {blurb=blue};
    \pic[scale=0.5] (b) at (1,0) {blurb={red, opacity=0.5}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I built the shape with the method of "let's try this". But you can draw the symbol as a frame line in `xfig` or `inkscape` and get the coordinates from there.

Comment: thanks very much for this - I am learning from it +1