# Define a variable containing color

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

We can define a variable and pass it to a module using

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\j{6}
```

Which it means j=6, How can I define a variable for a color, I mean I want to pass color to a module

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\colr{white}
```

But I encountered `Unknown function 'white'`. How can I solve it?!
I have the below code

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{array,textcomp}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{bayesnet}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{caption}
\pgfmathsetseed{5}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\rvdots}{%
  \vbox{
    \baselineskip4\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
    \kern-\p@
    \hbox{.}\hbox{.}\hbox{.}
  }}
\makeatother
\tikzset{main/.style={circle, minimum size = .1cm, thick, draw =black!80, node distance = 3mm},
         connect/.style={-latex, thick},
         box/.style={rectangle, draw=black}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[lds/.pic={j=#1,colr=#2,%<----- here is the variable
      \node[box,draw=\colr] (-Latent) {};
      \node[main,minimum size=.2cm, right=of -Latent] (-L1) {$x_1^{(\j)}$};
      \node[main,minimum size=.2cm] (-L2) [right=of -L1] {$x_2^{(\j)}$};
      \node[main,minimum size=.2cm] (-Lt) [right=5mm of -L2] {$x_T^{(\j)}$};
      \node[box,draw=white!100] (-Observed) [below=of -Latent] {};
      \node[main,fill=black,text=white,minimum size=.2cm] (-O1) [right=of -Observed,below=of -L1] {$y_1^{(\j)}$};
      \node[main,fill=black,text=white,minimum size=.2cm] (-O2) [right=of -O1,below=of -L2] {$y_2^{(\j)}$};
      \node[main,fill=black,text=white,minimum size=.2cm] (-Ot) [right=of -O2,below=of -Lt] {$y_T^{(\j)}$};
      \draw (-L1.east) edge [connect] (-L2);
      \node at (16,0) {$\dots$};
      \path (-L1.south) edge [connect] (-O1);
      \path (-L2.south) edge [connect] (-O2);
      \path (-Lt.south) edge [connect] (-Ot);
           },my text/.style={rounded corners=2pt, text width=10mm,     font=\sffamily, line width=.5pt, align=left},
      my arrow/.style={rounded corners=2pt, draw=green!15, line width=1.5mm, -{Triangle[]}}]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\j{6} 
    \def\colr{white} %<----here
    \pic(lds1) at (0,7){lds};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\def\colr{white}`?

Comment: no it does not work

Comment: Sahar, in which context do you try to use `\colr`? The `\def` should work in most cases... You may also try `\colorlet` if you are trying to define colors resulting from mixings.

Comment: I edited my question, and defined the variable, see the comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if the syntax you use at the beginning of the `pic` `lds` definition is legal, I never saw it like that, but my guess is that it is illegal. When you write `j=#1,colr=#2` my guess is that those tokens are simply ignored by tikz (unless it is a kind of key-value syntax I'm not aware of).

Later, in your "main" tikz code you define `\j`, and this is the reason why when you use `\j` later in your code it works, but the assignment `j=#1` has nothing to do with it. For the same reason, `\def\colr` in the "main" part of the figure should work too (in my test, it worked).

However, I think the correct syntax for passing several values to a `pic` (as explained for example in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167585/12571) is as follows:

```
\tikzset{
 pics/lds/.style 2 args={code={
 % ... here #1 and #2 can be used
 % ...
 }}
}
```

In your code, you should use `#1` instead of `\j` and `#2` instead of `\colr`. But also, if you prefer not changing your code, you can start the definition of `lds` pic as follows:

```
\tikzset{
 pics/lds/.style 2 args={code={
  \pgfmathsetmacro\j{#1}
  \def\colr{#2}
  % The remaining code is untouched
 }}
```

Later, to use this pic, you write: `\pic(lds1) at (0,7) {lds={6}{white}};`.

**Complete code**:

```
\tikzset{
main/.style={circle, minimum size = .1cm, thick, draw =black!80, node distance = 3mm},
connect/.style={-latex, thick},
box/.style={rectangle, draw=black},
pics/lds/.style 2 args={code={
      \pgfmathsetmacro\j{#1}
      \def\colr{#2}%<----- here is the variable
      \node[box,draw=\colr] (-Latent) {};
      \node[main,minimum size=.2cm, right=of -Latent] (-L1) {$x_1^{(\j)}$};
      \node[main,minimum size=.2cm] (-L2) [right=of -L1] {$x_2^{(\j)}$};
      \node[main,minimum size=.2cm] (-Lt) [right=5mm of -L2] {$x_T^{(\j)}$};
      \node[box,draw=white!100] (-Observed) [below=of -Latent] {};
      \node[main,fill=black,text=white,minimum size=.2cm] (-O1) [right=of -Observed,below=of -L1] {$y_1^{(\j)}$};
      \node[main,fill=black,text=white,minimum size=.2cm] (-O2) [right=of -O1,below=of -L2] {$y_2^{(\j)}$};
      \node[main,fill=black,text=white,minimum size=.2cm] (-Ot) [right=of -O2,below=of -Lt] {$y_T^{(\j)}$};
      \draw (-L1.east) edge [connect] (-L2);
      \node at (16,0) {$\dots$};
      \path (-L1.south) edge [connect] (-O1);
      \path (-L2.south) edge [connect] (-O2);
      \path (-Lt.south) edge [connect] (-Ot);
           }},
%my text/.style={rounded corners=2pt, text width=10mm,font=\sffamily, line width=.5pt, align=left},
%my arrow/.style={rounded corners=2pt, draw=green!15, line width=1.5mm, -{Triangle[]}}      
}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \pic(lds1) at (0,7) {lds={6}{white}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

In addition, I would prefer to use `\colorlet` instead of `\def` when definig colors. This means to change `\def\colr{#2}` by `\colorlet{colr}{#2}`, and then, when the color is needed, write it with the same syntax than any of the predefined colors, i.e., for example  `draw=colr` instead of `draw=\colr`.

This way you can define "mixings" based on the color received in `#2`, as for example: `\colorlet{myforeground}{#2!30!white}`, `\colorlet{mybackground}{#2!30!black}`.