# Scalable predefined parts of an image in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzscale

I am working on reusable image parts with Tikz. Thanks to the answer to [TikZ 3.0---Multiple arguments for `pic`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167556/tikz-3-0-multiple-arguments-for-pic#), I found out how to do macros with parameters.

But, the problem with using predefined pics is that `tikzscale` does not scale them with the rest of the image. Here a small example.

The main file contains the tikz macro and the include statements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzscale}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\tikzset{pics/tripile/.style args={#1}{code={
  \coordinate (top) at (0,#1);
  \foreach \i in{0,...,#1}
  \foreach \j in{0,...,\i}
  {
    \tikzmath{
      \y = .3*(2/3*#1-\i)*cos(30);
      \x = .3*(\i/2-\j);}
    \draw (\x,\y) circle (3pt);
  }
}}}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{test.tikz}
\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{test.tikz}
\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{test.tikz}
\end{document}
```

The file `test.tikz` then provides the image

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
  \draw (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- cycle;
  \pic at (1,1) {tripile=3};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output looks like

[image: wrong image]

but I would like the proportions between the square and the pile of circles to remain the same while scaling as in

[image: correct image]

Is there a way of defining a scalable pic?

Comment: By default, `pic`s don't scale. You can use the key `transform shape` to enable this behaviour (pgf manual p. 252/section 18.2, pic syntax). (I.e. `\pic at (1,1) [transform shape] {tripile=3};` Does that help you?

Comment: Great! If you write it as an answer, I can mark the problem as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, pics don't scale. You can use the key `transform shape` to enable this behaviour (pgf manual p. 252/section 18.2, pic syntax). In your particular example, this would be

```
\pic at (1,1) [transform shape] {tripile=3};
```

As a side-note, the pgf manual states that pics are slow; If you just draw circles, it may be faster to do this with nodes (which can be scaled using the same key, `transform shape`.)