# Define a pic with multiple argument and use them in for loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, texmaker, loops

I have drawn this:

[image]

With this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/message/.style={code={
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,1);
\draw foreach \X in {1,2,3} {(\X,0) -- (\X,1)}; 
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (0,0) {message};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now i would like to fill each square with a number passed as parameters (for the moment it will be just 1..4 but not in order.

So i would like to have something like

```
\draw pic[0,0] {message=1/2/3/4};
```

As seen in this queston: [TikZ 3.0---Multiple arguments for `pic`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167556/tikz-3-0-multiple-arguments-for-pic)
But i'm drawing each squares with a for loop and it would be interresting to keep this for loop in order to be able to draw a longer rectangle with more square and more parameters in the future.
So something like:

```
\draw foreach \X in {1,2,3} {(\X,0) -- (\X,1) node[pos= 0.5, right] {param #X+1}};
```

While declaring the first label when drawing the rectangle with the #1 param to get something like:

[image]

If i call the function like that:

```
\draw pic[0,0] {message=1/2/3/4};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/message/.style={code={
\draw (0,0) rectangle (4,1);
\draw foreach \X in {1,2,3} {(\X,0) -- (\X,1)}; 
\foreach \X [count=\Y,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {\Y-0.5}] in {#1}
{\node at (\Z,0.5) {\X};
\ifnum\Y=4
\breakforeach % make sure that the entries do not overshoot
\fi}
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (0,0) {message={1,A,F,2}};
\pic at (0,-2) {message={1,...,4}};
\pic at (0,-4) {message={3,...,14}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain me a bit this line `\foreach \X [count=\Y,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {\Y-0.5}] in {#1}` cause now i'm drawing these rectangle inside bigger one. And i'm calling the function of these rectangle to draw the ensemble and i would like to pass these parameters inside the 1sft function to give them later to the 2nd one who draw these little rectangle with labels

Comment: @Kokodelo I am sorry, I do not understand the question. `\foreach \X [count=\Y,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {\Y-0.5}] in {#1}` loops of the argument `#1`, a list, where `\Y` is the count, `1,2,...` and `\Z` is `Y-0.5`, which is used for the position.